# Is there any way to replace values with different values in the same row if they meet a certain condition using a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I need to replace the values of a certain cell with values from another cell if a certain condition is met.

```
for r in df: 
    if df['col1'] > 1 :
        df['col2'] 
    else:
```

I am hoping for every value in column 1 to be replaced with their respective value in column 2 if the condition if the value of the row in column 1 is greater than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to loop through the entire dataframe.

```
idx=df['col1']>1
df.loc[idx,'col1']=df.loc[idx,'col2']
```

Using a for loop

```
for _,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['col1']>1:
        row['col1']=row['col2']
    elif condition:
        #put assignment here
    else other_condition:
        #put assignment here
```

Comment: I would like to add some other arguments to it, is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Please post an [mcve] that is actually indicative of your problem.  The general approach is using `np.select`

Comment: @DominicNaimool take a look at the updated solution. Since you don't have any examples I can't really test this.

Comment: @cs95 Why not? The questioner specifically wants to loop through the dataframe. Though I agree it's not ideal

Comment: They don't know what they want. What they actually want is not what they think they want.

Comment: I am still an amateur with data-frames in python, if loops are not the best way to do it, I will take your word for it. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 4, 6]})

print(df)
print('----------')

# the condition here is A^2 == B
df.loc[df['A'] * df['A'] == df['B'], 'A'] = df['B']

print(df)
```

output

```
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  4
2  3  6
----------
   A  B
0  1  4
1  4  4
2  3  6
```